# Verify the integrity of the Google ID token by Php (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, google-api-php-client

I'm developing an application which has two sides: mobile side(IOS) and server-side (PHP, Laravel 5.4). I'm using google's own class to generate the google token and send them over to server in json format.

My Json looks like this:

```
["name": "ali farhangmehr", "email": "ali.farhangmehr@gmail.com", "google_image_url": https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-6KoifJgUUW0/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAA60/BbWD4fEDvHk/s100/photo.jpg, "googleToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjVlYTZiNzAzYjYzOTVmYzJlNWJkNmUzY2EwZjhiMzcxYTE0ODU5YjMifQ.eyJhenAiOiIyNTk3NjE1MTY5NjEtOXZ0Y3AyZnQ1dXZsaGJkdmxlM2lndDlsbDg3b3FwM2EuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiIyNTk3NjE1MTY5NjEtOXZ0Y3AyZnQ1dXZsaGJkdmxlM2lndDlsbDg3b3FwM2EuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDU4NzI5MzY5MDEzOTMwNjEyNTEiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImFsaS5mYXJoYW5nbWVockBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6IkN6S0htamlYOUhDM2JjaGZRTGJ3ZXciLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE1MDIwNDc4MjAsImV4cCI6MTUwMjA1MTQyMCwibmFtZSI6ImFsaSBmYXJoYW5nbWVociIsInBpY3R1cmUiOiJodHRwczovL2xoNS5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20vLTZLb2lmSmdVVVcwL0FBQUFBQUFBQUFJL0FBQUFBQUFBQTYwL0JiV0Q0ZkVEdkhrL3M5Ni1jL3Bob3RvLmpwZyIsImdpdmVuX25hbWUiOiJhbGkiLCJmYW1pbHlfbmFtZSI6ImZhcmhhbmdtZWhyIiwibG9jYWxlIjoiZW4ifQ.fMbcS3axTumt1hW4_Fss3C3QfLc_Ohhqlj3XfRkDmXixOlnEAV-9GaxI-6IOl0bdh382rJd2Ign4Fjdw8dJ5kGNhMmci9sV-_G50FU3vNH60RptJ04QX7BGrfUOjCJIV5dARJqsCNwqVWItR1F5z-gz9WHA0YKAjMCTWMWSuF03O0yowqzPoajwBLk5VNGOk7Q9fRvKEG7tnTGkckCBSBwWa5KdYnQw-k1OGB9W7qjcQrCelPE8SPzR_GwhHNoAGTOpZXQQSoeDNad8JWbExGZ9MeBDRoaLfLIoV7NRrVaSEwc4wSmga-yqlqjhGaULcdUGOZOasbhDyl28ULEDK2w"]
```

There is no problem so far. Then I have to check if the Google token is valid so I can register the user or log in the email
This is the link to the Google's own documentation on this matter
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

I followed everything and my PHP code looks like this:

```
$input = $request->all();
$google_token = $input['google_token'] = $request->input('googleToken');

$client_id = $CLIENT_ID; //from my google console
$client=new Google_Client(['client_id' => $client_id]);
$payload=$client->verifyIdToken($google_token);
$client->verifyIdToken($google_token);
if ($payload) {
 // do the login or register
} else {
  return false;
}
```

and every time I'm getting this error:

```
(1/1) SignatureInvalidException
Signature verification failed
in JWT.php (line 112)
```

[image: Error msg]

Answer (score 0):

this issue because of new JWT for firebase 
just use old version on JWT it will work

```
composer require firebase/php-jwt:4.0
```